# Behaviour of $\arctan(x) /x$ when $x\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by
>
> $$f(x) =\begin{cases} \dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x} & \text{ if }  x \neq 0 \\
> \\
> 1 & x = 0 \end{cases}  $$
>
> 1. $f$ is not differentiable at $0$
> 2. $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_0}{=}}1+o(x)$ and $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$
> 3. ${\displaystyle f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_0}{=}}1+x+o(x^{2})}$ et $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=1$
> 4. $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ and its derivative function is $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x(1+x^{2})}+\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x^{2}}$

My thoughts:

1. false :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x}-1}{x-0}=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\arctan \left(x\right)-x}{x^2}\right)=0 $$ (by hopital's rule) 
i don't know is there another way to prove it without  hopital's rule
so the limit exist which means that $f'(0)=0$

2 true from 1 and $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_0}{=}}1+o(x)$ equivalent of $f'(0) = 0$
since $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_0}{=}}1+o(x)\equiv f(x)-1=o(x)\equiv \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-1}{x}=0=f'(0)$

3 flase from 1

4.false :

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{*}\qquad f(x)=\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x}$

$$f'(x)=\left(\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)'=\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot x-\arctan(x)}{x^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{x(1+x^{2})}-\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x^{2}}$$

for that kind of question one statement is true but i found 1 and 4 are both true beside for the statement $2$ and $3$ i don't know how to prove them wrong or right

Comment: 1 says that $f$ is *not* differentiable, while you have shown it *is*. So 1 is *false*.

Comment: Oh my god  i didn't notice that thank u

Comment: And 4) is false, sign slip at the end.

Comment: Your finding in 1 implies either 2 or 3 (which, obviously, cannot hold simultaneously). Guess which one of them.

Comment: 1\implies 2 but we must check that $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_0}{=}}1+o(x)$$

Comment: This is equivalent to saying that $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you are right i didn't notice mines so 4 is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is ultimately answered by author. I make this community wiki to reduce the number of unanswered questions.

Comment: Zhoraster   but with ur help of course

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are good. Here's a different approach

The derivative is, for $x\ne0$,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{x\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}-\arctan x}{x^2}=
\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}-\frac{\arctan x}{x^2}
$$
In particular this shows that $f$ has derivatives of all order in every point $x\ne0$.

For deciding what happens at $0$, we can consider the Taylor series of $\arctan x$, that converges in the interval $(-1,1)$:
$$
\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\dots+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}+\dotsb
$$
and so
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\dots+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}+\dotsb
$$
which agrees with the definition at $0$; thus the function is, over $(-1,1)$, the sum of its Taylor series, in particular function is $C^{\infty}$ over $(-1,1)$ (and therefore also on the whole real line).

Note also that, in $(-1,1)$,
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{3}+\dots+(-1)^n\frac{2nx^{2n-1}}{2n+1}
$$
so $f'(0)=0$.